# Parsing data from XML and display it on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jsplumb

Currently I have this:

Notice the two boxes displayed are hard coded in, start from line 18 to line 70 in my HTML section. Now that I have a .XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collection>
 <beanRepresentation>
 <beanRepId>222</beanRepId>
 <beanRepName>Bean 1</beanRepName>
 <topY>0</topY>
 <leftX>0</leftX>
 <height>0</height>
 <width>0</width>
 </beanRepresentation>

 <beanRepresentation>
 <beanRepId>223</beanRepId>
 <beanRepName>Bean 2</beanRepName>
 <topY>0</topY>
 <leftX>0</leftX>
 <height>0</height>
 <width>0</width>
</beanRepresentation>

</collection>
```

I want to be able to parse this information and then display the boxes based on this .XML file, what should I use? jQuery? or just plain Javascript? Can someone help me with the example I posted here.

the `topY` is the `top`, and `leftX` is `left` for the HTML field respectively. beanRepName should be the name displayed on the box, beanRepId is the integer in `jsPlumb.draggable(id)` in my Jacascript file. So the four fields I need are topY, leftX, and beanRepId, and beanRepName.

Answer (score 0):

as you already use `jsPlumb` you can use [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) to parse the `xml` data in a searchable structure, iterate over it via `$.each` and create and insert new elements into the html page eg via

```
$('<div>')
.css({
    top:$currentxmlnode.find('topY').value()+'px'},
    ...
})
.appendTo(...);
```

Check the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) to learn how to retrieve the values from xml tree and [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to learn how to create new nodes